# Codemirror (AjaXplorer/Linux Webserver): ANSI-files with special characters

Tags: utf-8, codemirror, non-unicode, pydio

I have a AjaXplorer installation on a Linux Webserver.
One of the plugins of AjaXplorer is Codemirror - to view and edit text files.

Now I have the following situation: If I create a txt-File on Windows (ANSI) and upload it into Ajaxplorer (UTF-8), Codemirror shows every special character as a question mark. Consequently the whole file will be saved with question marks instead of the special characters.
But if a file once is saved in UTF-8, the special characters will be saved correctly.

So the problem exists in opening the ANSI-File. This is the point where I have to implement the solution, for example convert ANSI to UTF-8.

The 'funny' thing is, that if I open a fresh uploaded ANSI-File and a saved UTF-8 file with VIM on the Linux console, they look exactly the same, but the output in codemirror is different.

---

```
This is a uploaded ANSI-File with special characters like Ã¤ and Ã¶ and Ã¼
```

Output in Codemirror: 'like ? and ? and ?'

```
This is a saved UTF8-File with special characters like Ã¤ and Ã¶ and Ã¼
```

Output in Codemirror 'like ä and ö and ü'

---

This is the CodeMirror-Class of AjaXplorer and I think here must be the point where I could intervene:
https://github.com/mattleff/AjaXplorer/blob/master/plugins/editor.codemirror/class.CodeMirrorEditor.js

As you may see, I'm not a pro and I already tried some code pieces - otherwise I already had the solution ;-) I would be happy if someone gives me a hint! Thank you!!!